# Generate base64 DataURL from Image Source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas

I am trying to generate a base64 data URL from an image source, but whenever I try to convert it, the dataURL being output is of just the empty canvas without the image. What am I missing here?

src to base64 function:

```
imageToBase64(url, callback) {
    const img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function () {
        let canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.height = this.height;
        canvas.width = this.width;
        ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
        const dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png|gif|jpg');
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null;
    };
    img.src = url;
}
```

Usage:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.imageToBase64(this.props.originalUploadFile.data, (dataUrl) => {
        console.log(dataUrl) // I am getting a result, but it does not contain the image data
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me. http://jsbin.com/sahoza/edit?js,output

Comment: Could this be an issue with the url youre providing not matching the url that's being generated by webpack? Maybe try changing 
    img.src = url; to 
img.src = require(url). Just an idea.

Comment: Not related but your param for toDataURL is invalid, so it will default to `'image/png'`. For your issue, a good way to debug it is to append your image and your canvas in the document and see what they do look like. If you've got a result, it means that the image has been correctly loaded, so it is quite weird you don't have expected result.